# How can I get a video duration before/without playing

Tags: android

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
            {
              @Override
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
              {
                  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                  long duration= videoView.getDuration();

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  mShimmerDevice.stopStreaming();   
                  mShimmerDevice.stop();

              }

            });
       }
```

Though this code only works after the video had finished playing

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html). This way you can retrieve information about the video without loading/playing it.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(your_data_source);
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
```

Comment: It takes time to get video duration. since i pass array list it takes too much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the duration of your video before it starts playing by doing it inside `onPrepared()` method:

```
    //called when the mediaplayer is prepared to start buffering
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.i("tag","video length:" +mediaPlayer.getDuration());

                }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(your_data_source);
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
```